# Blazor: HttpContext.RequestServices provides a different scoped instance than IServiceProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I need to get a scoped instance from `HttpContext.RequestServices` (see: [Using Scoped dependencies in Singletons in ASP.NET Core](http://morgwai.pl/articles/aspdi.html)). The problem is that in Blazor-server rendering phase the instances injected to a constructor and returned from `HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService` are not the same.

Let's create a class of which we want to have a scoped instance

```
public class TestingClass {
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And a consumer class

```
public class ResultClass {
    public string result;

    public ResultClass(TestingClass fromInjection, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
        var fromRequest = contextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<TestingClass>();
        var fromServiceProvider = serviceProvider.GetService<TestingClass>();
        var requestXinjection = (fromRequest == fromInjection);
        var serviceXinjection = (fromServiceProvider == fromInjection);
        result = $"Instance in from request and injection is the same {requestXinjection}. Instance in from request and service provider is the same {serviceXinjection}";
    }
}
```

And `ConfigureServices`

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();           
services.AddScoped<TestingClass>();
services.AddTransient<ResultClass>();
```

Now let's inject the `ResultClass` instance to a Razor Page and  Blazor Component (`render-mode="ServerPrerendered"`)

On the **Razor Page** all three instances are the same:

> Instance in from request and injection is the same True. Instance in from request and service provider is the same True

In **blazor prerendering** phase all three instances are the same:

> Instance in from request and injection is the same True. Instance in from request and service provider is the same True

In **blazor rendering** phase the injected instance is different than the one from the request:

> Instance in from request and injection is the same **False**. Instance in from request and service provider is the same True

By my opinion in all cases all three instances must be the same. *Is it true?*

**Do I interpret DI behavior wrong way?** **Is it a bug?**

## Notes

When I set `render-mode="Server"` the behavior is the same as in rendering phase (False, True).

I use asp.net-core-3.1

Comment: Have you found out why such a behavior?

Comment: @AurelienB: The behavior was reported as a bug, but it was said that it is by design [Rendering a component: An injected scopeded instance differs from the one from RequestServices #20570](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20570). You can try to report it different way if you feel yourself more persuasive.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I find time to report it, not sure I will be better at convincing them tho. About the way they handle DI, coming from Guice, it feels wrong how .net Core behaves.